# Generated constructor data

Tags: typescript, nswag, njsonschema

I am using NSwag to generate a typescript client for a backend API. Ultimately, it ends up generating a method:

```js
login(request: LoginRequest): Promise<AuthResponse>
```

This is fine, however the problem is with the `LoginRequest` constructor. It generates like so:

```js
export class LoginRequest implements ILoginRequest {
    email!: string;
    password!: string;

    constructor(data?: ILoginRequest) {
        if (data) {
          // ...
        }
    }
}
```

As such, it allows `LoginRequest` to be created without any of the required data. I had a look at the source of the generator and it appears there is no option to change it.

Is there a way to force the constructor to make the `data` parameter required?

Note that I'm aware I could set the generation type to use interfaces, but then as far as I can see I would lose some of the parsing smarts (ie. date strings to date instances). If I could use only interfaces but retain that logic somehow that would be ideal.

Comment: Just make a wrapper for LoginRequest with required argument

Comment: That's not really a viable solution. Since it's generated code I don't want to be hand coding wrappers for every data type. At a minimum I would need to be able to hook the generator to do that, not sure if that is possible.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html ?

Comment: No, because then I would need to parse all the outputs to generate all the declaration merging.

Comment: I must admit - you have a pain )

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No, I ended up going with a different solution so I didn't pursue it any further.